# Remove last comma from a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a JavaScript method to return an array of database objects. The following Kendo UI template allows the items to be returned as a comma-separated string.

The problem is, a comma is always returned at the end of each string. Here's the code by the way:

```
    #for(var i = 0; i < Categories.length; i++){#
        #:Categories[i].CategoryName#,
    #}#
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know how you will use this but this regex will help you
**str.replace(/,(?=[^,]*$)/, '')**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this template:

```
 #for(var i = 0; i < Categories.length; i++){#
      #if(i+1 === Categories.length){#
        #:Categories[i].replace(/,/g,'')#
        #} else{#
        #:Categories[i].CategoryName#
      #}#
    #}#
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I've made an edit to reflect the solution that worked. For some reason, replace didn't do the job.

Comment: Ok, I thought the comma is coming from the data only thats why used the replace method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in plain javascript

```
Categories.slice(0,-1);
```

Here Categories is the variable from you want to remove last "," (comma)